# Html Canvas Particle system

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am very new to the HTML canvas and so far the only way I've used it is with the p5.js framework. I have a particle system in which I want the particles to chase my cursor. However, they won't show up, although the inspector isn't throwing any errors:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var mouseX, mouseY;
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("stars");

function star(X, Y) {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.size = getRandomArbitrary(3, 5);
}
star.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y, this.size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
star.prototype.update = function() {
    // var mousePos = getMousePos(ctx, e);
    var xvel = this.x - mouseX;
    var yvel = this.y -  mouseY;
    Math.max(1, Math.min(xvel, 7));
    Math.max(1, Math.min(yvel, 7));
    this.x += xvel;
    this.y += yvel;
}
function starSystem(Num) {
    this.stars = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
        this.stars.push(new star(getRandomArbitrary(0, ctx.width), getRandomArbitrary(0, ctx.height)));
    }
}
starSystem.prototype.run = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {   
        this.stars[i].update();
        this.stars[i].draw();
    }
}

// ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
var ss = new starSystem(50);
function iterate(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    ss.run();
}
```

Here is my canvas tag:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" onmousemove="iterate(event)">
</canvas>
```

I wouldn't want to call the iterate function this way (I would rather just use a `setInterval`) but this seems the easiest way I can get hold of the event variable `e` so I can calculate the mouse position. (See my `iterate` function)
My main question is: why isn't the `draw` function for the stars creating any visible results on the canvas? I know my code is probably very messy and unconventional, but I would like to know what is the most efficient way to get the particles to draw on the screen. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please debug starSystem.prototype.run function for example console.log(this.stars) to see if any element pushed.

Comment: `console.log(this.stars)` shows 50 star Objects, as expected

Comment: Thanks for the tip on random, I replaced the random with a function I found on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: `ss.stars[0].draw ` shows the star draw function, and also if I place a console log in the star draw function it fires every time I more the mouse ;D

Comment: `ctx` doesn't have an `width` or an `height` properties, you want the ones from your canvas, `c`, or from `ctx.canvas` (it's the same). Also your `Math.max(1, Math.min(xvel, 7));` is not declaring anything, I gues you wanted `xvel =   Math.max(1, Math.min(xvel, 7));`.